# Trouble implementing Facebook page tab competition

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

I am developing a Facebook page tab that will hold a competition.

So firstly there is the fan gate, I have implemented that easy enough with the Facebook php sdk and the signed request.

When the user gets through the fan gate I.e liked the page. There is a form with entry details.

Now I can only allow someone to enter the competition once.

So what I tried was to get the user id, but depending on the Facebook account I either get back the ID or else I get the user ID =0.

Is there any way for me to get a unique value so I can store that the user has entered the competition without having to allow access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user id is given in the signed request only if the user has given permissions to the application.

Comment: How would I implement a competition like this then?? So if the user was to revisit the page it would display a thank u for entering the competition

Comment: The solid way is to request basic permissions via ouath, ie if user_id in the signed_request is empty, redirect the user to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL`, once they give you the basic permissions, redirect them back to your app, and then you'll have access to their user_id and you can take it from there. FB oauth - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: ... of course, requesting permissions will inevitably lose some entries; a much better way would be just to ask users to enter their name and email in a simple form and don't worry about duplicate entries - it's a trade off between # of entries and it is up to the clients to decide which way they prefer

Comment: I could do it per email aswell, so at least I can notify them that they are in the competition, I dont want to request permissions.

Comment: I remember before there was a way to log a user in via FB javascript SDK (something like "require login" via ajax) which only required a user action, e.g. click, and you could get user data via something like FB.getSession but I don't think that is available anymore since the move to oauth; anyways, I believe the solution based on email address is better and that way you can use it even for users outside of facebook